# WPF binding not working on custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

I have been struggling with this for three days now and I feel I am very close to a solution, but I just can't get there.

I am making a sudoku puzzle and I would like to create a custom control to display one of the nine 3x3 grids, so I dan display nine of them and have a nice 9x9 grid.

I have found at least 30 different pages that should explain how to create this but I could not find the solution on each of them.

I think the problem lays in the `PartialSudokuGrid` because the `Values` property doesn't seem to get called. Also, no errors are displayed in the output window. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Not meaning to dump code and expect someone to fix it, but I am really stuck on this and I feel as if it is just a little change that will make everything work.

Here is my code:

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="SudokuWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SudokuWPF"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400"
    DataContext="{Binding PartialSudokuGrid, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="3">
        <local:PartialSudokuGrid Values="{Binding ValuesVM}" />
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class PartialSudokuGridVM : ViewModelBase {

    private int[] _values;

    public PartialSudokuGridVM() {
        this.ValuesVM = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    }

    public int[] ValuesVM {
        get {
            return this._values;
        }
        set {
            this._values = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SudokuWPF.PartialSudokuGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Values}">

    <UniformGrid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding [0]}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding [1]}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding [2]}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding [3]}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding [4]}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding [5]}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding [6]}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding [7]}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding [8]}" />
    </UniformGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class PartialSudokuGrid : UserControl {

        public PartialSudokuGrid() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public int[] Values {
            get {
                return (int[])GetValue(ValuesProperty);
            }
            set {
                SetValue(ValuesProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty ValuesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Values", typeof(int[]), typeof(PartialSudokuGrid));
    }
```

Fix:

Like MDoobie suggested, I removed the `Self` binding from the PartialGridView and cleared the codebehind file (no use anymore).

old:

```
<local:PartialSudokuGrid Values="{Binding ValuesVM}" />
```

new:

```
<local:PartialSudokuGrid DataContext="{Binding ValuesVM}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you set the Window's DataContext with this line `DataContext="{Binding PartialSudokuGrid, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`

It is set the PartialSudokuGrid not the PartialSudokuGridVM (which has the ValuesVM property). Try to set the PartialSudokuGridVm as DataContext.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I thought the binding filled the property in the PartialSudokuGrid, but didn't. Awesome! I'll edit my answer to show what was the fix.

Comment: I'm glad I'd helped you.